# Cannot add row to SQL Server View

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, ssms

I have a View which is comprised of two tables, TABLE_ONE and TABLE_TWO.

These two tables are linked by their primary key: PKT_UID (see pic).

I have added two rows to the two tables and given them the same PKT_UID but the View is not displaying any rows with this PKT_UID when I search the view for that UID.

I don't know much about SQL views, but my understanding was that as long as the two rows from both tables are linked by the same primary key, it should display in the view. What am I missing?

**VIEW CODE:**

````
SELECT        dbo.TABLE_ONE.PKT_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.IT_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.SKT_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.RMS_XSP, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.S_MT, dbo.TABLE_ONE.E_MT, dbo.TABLE_ONE.KILP, dbo.TABLE_ONE.KILT, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.IIC, dbo.TABLE_ONE.L_D, dbo.TABLE_ONE.S_D, dbo.TABLE_ONE.S_DAM, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.E_DF, dbo.TABLE_ONE.E_DFD, dbo.TABLE_ONE.H_U, dbo.TABLE_ONE.JK, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.JKT, dbo.TABLE_ONE.TRCE, dbo.TABLE_ONE.MOD, dbo.TABLE_ONE.TAK, dbo.TABLE_ONE.DG_AR, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.DG_LENGTH, dbo.TABLE_ONE.XSP_OFF, dbo.TABLE_ONE.JIK_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.FA_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.JOB, dbo.TABLE_TWO.PKT_UID AS GULL_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.GULL_T_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.GULL_FRC_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_TWO.GULLOPP_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.RMMS_XSP, dbo.TABLE_ONE.GANG, dbo.TABLE_ONE.TRM_BSD_DATE, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.DOLM, dbo.TABLE_ONE.DONM, dbo.TABLE_TWO.GULLM_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.AR_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_TWO.PAR_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.RCT_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.PG_C, dbo.TABLE_TWO.RCT_YN_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_TWO.SCHD_TM_UID, dbo.TABLE_ONE.NRS, dbo.TABLE_TWO.BS_M, dbo.TABLE_TWO.EMB_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_TWO.MNG_REQ_UID, dbo.TABLE_TWO.FORM_R, dbo.TABLE_TWO.FORM_R_NAME, dbo.TABLE_TWO.SCHED_UID, 
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE.SH_G, dbo.TABLE_ONE.SH_GT, dbo.TABLE_TWO.PKT_UID AS IT_N, CAST(dbo.TABLE_TWO.PKT_UID AS char(15)) 
                         AS GULL_NAME, dbo.TABLE_TWO.PACK
FROM            dbo.TABLE_TWO INNER JOIN
                         dbo.TABLE_ONE ON dbo.TABLE_TWO.PKT_UID = dbo.TABLE_ONE.PKT_UID
WHERE        (dbo.TABLE_ONE.IT_UID = 1160) AND (dbo.TABLE_ONE.E_DFD = 0)```
````

Comment: What is the full code for the view? Does it have a WHERE clause?

Comment: Does the view's SELECT return the expected result executed stand-alone?

Comment: @BarneyL Thanks! you solved my problem. There was a WHERE clause in the view code that was not being fulfilled. I didn't realise this as it's my first time setting up a view like this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    rm_c.ITEM_UID
   ,rm_g.ITEM_UID 

FROM
    RM_COMMON_ATTRIBUTES rm_c
LEFT JOIN RM_GULLY_2010_A rm_g
    ON rm_g.ITEM_UID = rm_c.ITEM_UID
```

If this shows both UIDs as matching then it's not the table

If you're using report builder (have you tried refreshing all fields)

Answer (score 0):

Solved thanks to @BarneyL. There was a `WHERE RM_COMMON_ATTRIBUTES.ITEM_TYPE_UID = 1160` condition in the view code that was not being fulfilled.